# how to programmatically add more than one item in a webForm asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to programmatically add item (like label, table, ...) in my webForm. I tried to create an event click on a button, to add labels each clicks. But every time, it stops to one label, and then nothing happens for the next clicks.

Here's my code for those who want to see what I tried :

```
protected void btn_Valid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
               this.Page.Form.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "test" });
    }
```

Can we do this in asp.net or should I use another language (like javascript) ?

Answer (score 3):

It only creates one Label because that one Label is lost during PostBack. 
In your click-event, you have to increase a counter for labels (and/or other controls), and recreate those in `Page_Init`. EACH and EVERY time the Page posts back. Memorize that counter in the ViewState.
And as usual, I recommend this article about the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

For those who want a real anwser to this follow this step, it works for me :

1. Make creation (and not instanciation) in the Page_Init or Page_Load, because for each events those methods are called,
2. For the example above, don't do kind of `this.Page.Forms.Controls.Add(lbl_test)`, try to find another way like storing the data of those label (in a String Array for example). Here's the code example :

`protected void btn_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    tabLabel[count_tabLabel] = "hello world";
// Do the if(IsCallBack) {} for avoid having your first label skipped
    count_tabLabel++;
}`

3. In the Page_Load() function (basically written in the .cs) or by creating the function bellow, do a loop to add those labels to your webForm like this :

`protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cpt_l; i++)
        {
            Page.Form.Controls.Add(tabLabel[count_tabLabel]);
        }
}`

In fact the page is automatically reloaded, that is the asp page cycle life. So you need at each modifications on your webForm to reload all your items like labels, or more complexes things.

Hope it helps !

P.S.:

Comment: This is not "a real answer", far from it.

Comment: Let us know your solution, don't make random sentences Igor. It is not a philosophical site. Anyway, I forgot the "IsCallBack" test, without it the page doesn't display the first instance of the label. It make a gap between the first label and the second, so it diplsay from the second one and avoid the previous label for this solution.

Comment: What is `tabLabel`, how is it declared and instantiated, how does it keep its items between requests? What are `count_tabLabel` and `cpt_l`? `Page.Form.Controls.Add` takes a control, not a string. It is not "IsCallBack" - "IsPostBack".

Comment: Definitely do NOT create controls dynamically in `Page_Load`. It's not where they belong, because by then, the ViewState has already been processed. If you create textboxes dynamically and type something into them, that content will be lost during your next PostBack if you create the controls that late.
BTW, elaborate on "real answer", please.

Comment: @Alexander - `Page_Load` is the latest `Page` event were dynamic controls can be created and still obtain their relevant information from `ViewState` and `Request`.

Comment: The `ViewState` is loaded and the contents are put into the controls "during load", but before the `Page_Load` event.